# SKLearn MLP Classifier returning meaningless Rating values

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I'm making a MLP Classifier using SKLearn. I have a dataframe consisting of 'age', 'book_title', 'book_author', 'year_of_publication', 'publisher', 'Category' and 'country' and I want to predict 'rating' for them, ranging from 0-10.

I've encoded entire string columns (like 'book_author' and 'publisher') using LabelEncoder() and scaled all columns (because MLP is too sensitive) using StandardScaler(), so my X_train dataset looks like this:

```
    age book_title  book_author year_of_publication publisher   Category    country
0   -0.183911   1.255606    -0.122783   0.271406    -0.814572   0.685256    0.427726
1   -0.183911   1.255606    -0.122783   0.271406    -0.814572   0.685256    0.427726
2   -0.084496   1.255606    -0.122783   0.271406    -0.814572   0.685256    0.427726
3   -0.680984   1.255606    -0.122783   0.271406    -0.814572   0.685256    0.427726
4   -0.482155   1.255606    -0.122783   0.271406    -0.814572   0.685256    0.427726
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
131174  -1.078643   0.146868    -0.689864   -1.438894   -0.566305   -0.520461   0.427726
131175  2.599699    0.146868    -0.689864   -1.438894   -0.566305   -0.520461   0.427726
131176  1.704967    0.146868    -0.689864   -1.438894   -0.566305   -0.520461   0.427726
131177  0.114333    0.146868    -0.689864   -1.438894   -0.566305   -0.520461   0.427726
131178  -0.183911   0.146868    -0.689864   -1.438894   -0.566305   -0.520461   0.427726
```

Training MLP classifier:

```
clf = MLPClassifier(
    hidden_layer_sizes=(50,50,50),
    max_iter=2000,
    activation='tanh',
    solver='adam'
    ).fit(X_train, Y_train)
```

While trying to predict ratings:

```
Y_pred = clf.predict(X_test)
Y_pred.nonzero()
```

I get something like:

```
(array([   91,   133,   223,   319,   392,   410,   441,   517,   675,
          741,   941,   951,  1173,  1195,  1215,  1400,  1406,  1410,
         1488,  1521,  1534,  1614,  1668,  1735,  1827,  1847,  1888,
         2048,  2051,  2111,  2115,  2206,  2357,  2384,  2501,  2556,
         2595,  2633,  2650,  2721,  2763,  2806,  2860,  2986,  3147,
         3208,  3240,  3247,  3282,  3393,  3446,  3708,  3884,  3974,
         3987,  4184,  4219,  4317,  4544,  4639,  4762,  4833,  4841,
         ...
```

Which obviously are not suitable ratings.

What can I fix in the code so the returned ratings range from 0-10?

Thanks in advance!

Edit: I've scaled X_test as well:

```
age book_title  book_author year_of_publication publisher   Category    country
0   -0.077752   0.866863    0.611836    0.833366    0.492138    0.691504    0.416835
1   -0.178117   0.226488    -0.247449   0.833366    1.173585    -1.312952   0.416835
2   -0.278482   0.834665    0.446589    -1.618859   -0.581657   -0.444354   0.416835
3   -0.278482   1.009964    0.735772    0.078835    1.503983    -1.312952   0.416835
4   0.825535    1.521548    -0.305286   0.267468    1.545283    0.691504    0.416835
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
32790   2.331013    -0.825302   -0.305286   0.833366    0.079140    -1.312952   0.416835
32791   -0.178117   1.110134    -1.619001   0.078835    0.533438    0.691504    0.416835
32792   -1.081404   1.099401    -0.420959   -0.298430   -0.808806   0.691504    0.416835
32793   1.929552    -0.249322   -1.693362   0.833366    -1.345704   0.691504    0.416835
32794   -0.178117   -1.590890   -0.718404   -0.298430   0.987736    -0.577985   0.416835
```

Comment: Have you transformed your X_test using the same standardscaler() instance that you used on X_train?

Comment: @Shaukat actually yes, I'll add it in post